# Setting multiple alarms with alarm manager

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to set multiple alarms with alarm manager. The problem I have is that only the first alarm I set works. Every alarm set after the first doesn't work. This is the function to set the alarm:

```
private void setAlarm(long time){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyAlarm.class);
    int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,id,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time,alarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);
}
```

In my onCreate function I have all my timepickers with an onClickListener that calls this function when a time is picked.

```
time1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(TimeSet.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    int hour = selectedHour % 12;
                    time1begin.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d %s", hour == 0 ? 12 : hour,
                            selectedMinute, selectedHour < 12 ? "am" : "pm"));


                }
            }, hour, minute, true);
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
            mTimePicker.show();
            setAlarm(mcurrentTime.getTimeInMillis());
        }
    });
```

How do I make it so multiple alarms are set?

Comment: Can you make confirm when you fire multiple times the function `setAlarm(...)` that `id` taken from System.currentTimeMillis(); is giving you different values instead of giving the same value? (Try with `Log.d("REQUESTCODE", "My id: "+id);`)

Comment: @denis_lor yes it does give different values. D/REQUESTCODE: My id: 1726197419 , D/REQUESTCODE: My id: 1726225957, D/REQUESTCODE: My id: 1726231537

Comment: Can you check the timezone which emulator takes. Sometimes, we schedule for `Local Timezone`, but `emulator` schedules for `GMT timezone`?

Comment: I think I found the issue, can you check my answer?

Comment: @denis_lor the time on my PC and emulator are the same

Comment: can you check they are being scheduled `adb shell dumpsys alarm`?

Comment: Doing this gives me such a long output it doesn't fit in my cmd and the top part gets cut off. I have no idea what the output means so I just copied into pastebin: https://pastebin.com/FNWQipKK